# Save string from a textbox in child form (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, methods

I'm coding in Visual Basic on the Visual Studio platform.

I have a child form, which consists of many text boxes. I have to make a Save and Save As method, which reads from theses text boxes and puts each read line in a seperate line in a text file.

Can anyone, please, help me with this one? I can't seem to understand how to do this. Been playing with this for hours now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What code do you have so far? Don't post it all, just say how far along you've got. Have you managed to get all your strings together and are ready to write?

Comment: I wrote the Open method, which reads the texts from a text file and puts the text in text boxes according to the preset format (1st line in 1st box etc.). From what you wrote, I understand that at first I have to read the code from the boxes at first, don't I?

Comment: Well, if you want to write what's in the text boxes to a file, yes, you have to read your text boxes first, then save. Do you have a Save method?

Comment: No, I don't, but I'll start working on it. Any tips on how to do it will be appreciated greatly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Dim mFileOutput As String = ""
Dim mStrWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\test.txt")
mFileOutput &= TextBox1.Text & vbCrLf
mFileOutput &= TextBox2.Text & vbCrLf
mStrWriter.Write(mFileOutput)
mStrWriter.Flush()
```